# Eclipse code assist and phpDoc

Tags: php, eclipse, phpdoc, eclipse-pdt, content-assist

I am using Eclipse for PHP Developers, Version: Neon Milestone 4 (4.6.0M4).
I am trying to make code assistant to show my custom functions in a bubble:

```
<?php
/**
 * This is foo
 * @param unknown $a
 * @param unknown $b
 */
function foo($a,$b){
    echo $a+$b;
}
```

The function appears in the Outline:
[image]

but it does not appear in the Content Assist bubble: 
[image]

Is autocomplete for a custom function possible?
What can I do?

Comment: According to the eclipse manual it is - you can use standard phpDoc markup.  http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/phpdoc_comments.htm or http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/code_assist_concept.htm - I used this in the past and it worked.  However I have abandoned eclipse for NuSphere phpEd so I can't verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly I found the answer, it is related to eclipse index files

http://www.oneminuteinfo.com/2012/09/solving-eclipse-auto-complete-issues.html?m=1

Comment: It would be more useful to copy the pertinent information into your answer (but still cite the link for credit).